# Hide text if font not available or fails to load in CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I am using the `@font-face` rule to create a font for a fictional language on my web pages. This works fine for full-featured desktop browsers, but some browsers, particularly mobile browsers, do not support loading fonts this way. The result is that my pages have weird encoded text on them if viewed via some browsers, which I would like to hide somehow.

There is no available alternative for this font, as it is not merely stylistic, but actually translates a character encoding system to the appropriate symbols.

What I would like to do is only display the text to which the fictional language's CSS class is applied if the browser is able to use `@font-face`, and otherwise, hide it via `display: none;` or some trick. However, I have been unable to find any method of doing this.

Alternatively, it would be acceptable to swap all the characters for some sort of "invalid character-character", as at least then the user will have some idea what they are looking at. However, the font is implemented using typical Latin letters as codes (0-9, a-Z), so merely failing to load the font does not already display them as invalid characters.

Comment: what if the font is normal font like sans-serif or arial? How the characters look?

Comment: @BhojendraNepal They look like complete out of place nonsense, which is why I'd like to hide it. For example, "n8D48aL4NA".

Comment: The only way I can think then is to check if the font-family is applied or not via javascript and then hide it. (I'm still unsure if we can check the font-family is applied or not for such case)

Comment: @BhojendraNepal JS might be workable, although not preferable; if it's possible, it's definitely an option. However, I have comparatively little experience with JS, especially something like this.

Comment: I have found this which might be helpful to you :) https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/font-loading.html

Comment: @BhojendraNepal Thanks for that link. It does look helpful, so I will probably use a variant of that. Turns out MediaWikis (the thing I am doing this on) actually support custom JS, anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You may try [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader).

It will append the classes in `HTML` such as `.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-loading`, `.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-active` and `.wf-<familyname>-<fvd>-inactive`.

You can use `CSS` to hide on loading state.